# Get all column values from all JTable (ex: three tables)

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Am struggling to get it working, have three tables trying to get all column values from all JTable(s) (Three tables) by clicking button "Read All Values".

When I use **Vector data = tableModel.getDataVector();**, returns only all columns values of the last table initiated.

Please give me directions, Thanks.

CODE:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class readAllJTableItem {

    private JFrame frame;
    private static JTextArea textAreaSD;
    private static JTextArea textAreaPI;
    private static JTextArea textAreaVL;
    private TitledBorder textAreaTitleBorder = new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Item(s)");

    private static JCheckBox checkBoxTypeOne;
    private static JCheckBox checkBoxTypeTwo;
    private static JCheckBox checkBoxTypeThree;

    //Table items
    private JScrollPane scrollTableSD;
    private JScrollPane scrollTablePI;
    private JScrollPane scrollTableVL;

    private JTable itemsTableSD;
    private JTable itemsTablePI;
    private JTable itemsTableVL;

    private DefaultTableModel tableModel;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    readAllJTableItem window = new readAllJTableItem();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public readAllJTableItem() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 872, 587);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final ArrayList<String> addItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        final int stedCntLpt_1[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}; //total = 12
        final int stedCntLpt_2[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13}; //total = 13
        final int stedCntLpt_3[] = {0,1,3,7,14,15,16,17}; //total = 8

        //Type-1 (0-11)
        addItems.add(0, "Column-01"); addItems.add(1, "Column-02"); addItems.add(2, "Column-03"); addItems.add(3, "Column-04");
        addItems.add(4, "Column-05"); addItems.add(5, "Column-06"); addItems.add(6, "Column-07"); addItems.add(7, "Column-08");
        addItems.add(8, "Column-09"); addItems.add(9, "Column-10"); addItems.add(10, "Column-11"); addItems.add(11, "Column-12");
        addItems.add(12, "Column-13"); addItems.add(13, "Column-14");
        addItems.add(14, "Column-15"); addItems.add(15, "Column-16"); addItems.add(16, "Column-17"); addItems.add(17, "Column-18");

        //1
        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Read All Values");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                //if (checkBoxTypeOne.isSelected() == true){
                //This is were you get the cell values of each JTable
//@camickr's code... 
DefaultTableModel model1 = (DefaultTableModel)itemsTableSD.getModel();
                                Vector data1 = model1.getDataVector();
                                System.out.println(data1.toString());
                //}
            }
        });
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(281, 487, 125, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);

        checkBoxTypeOne = new JCheckBox("SD");
        checkBoxTypeOne.setBounds(685, 196, 87, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(checkBoxTypeOne);
        checkBoxTypeOne.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {//checkbox has been selected
                    callRenderTable(textAreaSD, scrollTableSD, itemsTableSD, addItems, stedCntLpt_1, 3, 12);

                } else {
                    textAreaSD.setVisible(true);
                    scrollTableSD.setVisible(false);
                };
            }

        });

        checkBoxTypeTwo = new JCheckBox("PI");
        checkBoxTypeTwo.setBounds(682, 288, 44, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(checkBoxTypeTwo);
        checkBoxTypeTwo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    callRenderTable(textAreaPI, scrollTablePI, itemsTablePI, addItems, stedCntLpt_2, 4, 13);

                } else {
                    textAreaPI.setVisible(true);
                    scrollTablePI.setVisible(false);
                };
            }

        });

        checkBoxTypeThree = new JCheckBox("VL");
        checkBoxTypeThree.setBounds(685, 374, 55, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(checkBoxTypeThree);
        checkBoxTypeThree.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    callRenderTable(textAreaVL, scrollTableVL, itemsTableVL, addItems, stedCntLpt_3, 2, 8);

                } else {
                    textAreaVL.setVisible(true);
                    scrollTableVL.setVisible(false);
                };
            }

        });

        textAreaSD = new JTextArea();
        textAreaSD.setBounds(43, 166, 608, 87);
        textAreaSD.setBorder(textAreaTitleBorder);
        textAreaSD.setBackground(new Color(240,240,240));
        textAreaSD.setEditable(false);
        textAreaSD.setVisible(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textAreaSD);

        scrollTableSD = new JScrollPane();
        scrollTableSD.setBounds(43, 166, 608, 87);
        scrollTableSD.setVisible(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollTableSD);

        textAreaPI = new JTextArea();
        textAreaPI.setBounds(43, 256, 608, 103);
        textAreaPI.setBorder(textAreaTitleBorder);
        textAreaPI.setBackground(new Color(240,240,240));
        textAreaPI.setEditable(false);
        textAreaPI.setVisible(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textAreaPI);

        scrollTablePI = new JScrollPane();
        scrollTablePI.setBounds(43, 256, 608, 103);
        scrollTablePI.setVisible(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollTablePI);

        textAreaVL = new JTextArea();
        textAreaVL.setBounds(43, 362, 608, 71);
        textAreaVL.setBorder(textAreaTitleBorder);
        textAreaVL.setBackground(new Color(240,240,240));
        textAreaVL.setEditable(false);
        textAreaVL.setVisible(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textAreaVL);

        scrollTableVL = new JScrollPane();
        scrollTableVL.setBounds(43, 362, 608, 71);
        scrollTableVL.setVisible(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollTableVL);

        itemsTableSD = new JTable();
        scrollTableSD.setViewportView(itemsTableSD);

        itemsTablePI = new JTable();
        scrollTablePI.setViewportView(itemsTablePI);

        itemsTableVL = new JTable();
        scrollTableVL.setViewportView(itemsTableVL);
    }

    private void callRenderTable(JTextArea textArea, JScrollPane scrollTable, JTable itemsTable, ArrayList<String> addItems, int itemIndexNo[], int loopCount, int totCount){
        textArea.setVisible(false);
        scrollTable.setVisible(true);

        //DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(){
        tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(){
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column){
                switch(column){
                case 0:
                    return String.class;
                case 1:
                    return Boolean.class;
                case 2:
                    return String.class;
                case 3:
                    return Boolean.class;
                case 4:
                    return String.class;
                case 5:
                    return Boolean.class;
                default:
                    return String.class;
                }
            }
            int row = 0;
            int column = 1;
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[]{false, true, false, true, false, true};
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                if (row == 0 && column == 1){
                    return false;}
                return canEdit[column];
            }
        };
        //Assign the model to table
        itemsTable.setModel(tableModel);

        tableModel.addColumn("Items");
        tableModel.addColumn("Select");
        tableModel.addColumn("Items");
        tableModel.addColumn("Select");
        tableModel.addColumn("Items");
        tableModel.addColumn("Select");

        //The row
        int indIncr = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i <= loopCount; i++){

            tableModel.addRow(new Object[0]);

            for(int j = 0; j <= 2; j++){

                if (j == 0 && indIncr < totCount){
                    tableModel.setValueAt(addItems.get(itemIndexNo[indIncr]), i, j);
                    tableModel.setValueAt(true, i, j+1);
                    indIncr = indIncr + 1;}
                if (j == 1 && indIncr < totCount ){
                    tableModel.setValueAt(addItems.get(itemIndexNo[indIncr]), i, j+1);
                    tableModel.setValueAt(true, i, j+2);
                    indIncr = indIncr + 1;}
                if (j == 2 && indIncr < totCount){
                    tableModel.setValueAt(addItems.get(itemIndexNo[indIncr]), i, j+2);
                    tableModel.setValueAt(true, i, j+3);
                    indIncr = indIncr + 1;}
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have one variable "tableModel" so how do you expect that variable to reference 3 table models?

You have 3 variables to reference each of your 3 tables.

So you need code like:

```
DefaultTableModel model1 = (DefaultTableModel)itsTableSD.getModel();
DefaultTableModel model2 = (DefaultTableModel)itsTablePI.getModel();
DefaultTableModel model3 = (DefaultTableModel)itsTableVL.getModel();
```

Now you can use the getDataVector() method on each of the table models.

Also, get rid of your static variables. In general variables should not be static.

Comment: Thanks @camickr, Awesome! works suberb! **get rid of your static variables** Could you also please point out the 'Static variables' which I have used in my code, so that I can correct myself, still learning...Thx

Comment: @Java.beginner, I meant get rid of the "static" keyword on your variables. `still learning` - be consistent. Some of your variables use the static keyword other don't. Why the difference if you don't know what it means?